# Wildcards in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I am working with a DB2 database AS/400 and am looking at pulling all item numbers from the item table that end in the letter `A`.

```
SELECT *
FROM NRPDTA.IM
WHERE IMITNO LIKE '%A';
```

The query returns an empty set. I know the item number `300072A` exists in this table. The data type for the column is set to `character` fwiw. What am I missing syntactically to pull this off?

Comment: What will be result if you try `WHERE IMITNO LIKE '300072A' `?

Comment: Also try to use `WHERE RTRIM(IMITNO) LIKE '%A';`

Comment: @MegaTron It results in the same empty set. If I switch LIKE with = and '%A' with 300072A then it will pull the result for 300072A.

Answer (score 4):

Values of the `CHARACTER` data type are padded with spaces to the column length. If, for example, `IMITNO` is defined as `CHARACTER(10)`, the value stored would actually be `"300072A   "`. You might try to modify your `WHERE` clause like so:

```
...WHERE RTRIM(IMITNO) LIKE '%A'
```

or

```
...WHERE IMITNO LIKE '%A %'
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentations](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000751.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-2-12-9):

If the pattern specified in a `LIKE` predicate is a parameter marker, and a fixed-length character host variable is used to replace the parameter marker, the value specified for the host variable must have the correct length. If the correct length is not specified, the select operation will not return the intended results.

For example, if the host variable is defined as `CHAR(10)`, and the value `WYSE%` is assigned to that host variable, the host variable is padded with blanks on assignment. The pattern used is:

```
'WYSE%     '
```

The database manager searches for all values that start with `WYSE` and that end with five blank spaces. If you want to search only for values that start with `'WYSE'`, assign a value of `'WSYE%%%%%%'` to the host variable.